# Load Panel from custom module?

Tags: panels, features, importing-exporting

Anyone know of a way to export all the data found in a panel layout, context e.g. into a custom module in order to deploy from development to production?

Something like with views via the Implements hook_views_api() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module to export your panel page in form of a module.